# Mocking method from protected abstract method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

Here's my problem in detail.

Setup:

- I have class A that has a private member variable of class B.
- A method(method1) in class A calls a non-static method(method2)
  in class B.
- Class B actually inherits method2 from a protected abstract class C and does not override it.

Problem:

- I'm writing a test for class A.
- In the test I'm mocking the call to method2.

Sample Code:

```
B b = Mockito.mock(B.class);
A a = new A(b);
Mockito.when(b.method2()).thenReturn(MY_LIST);
```

- Now when I call method1(which in turn calls method2), I get a
  NullPointerException.

Sample Code:

```
a.method1();
```

- I'm assuming that this call is completely independent of the implementation of method2 since I'm mocking it. Is that wrong ? If not, what am I doing wrong ?

PS: class C is protected and Class A is in a different package from class B and C.

Comment: post your code with explanation

Comment: I'm not at liberty to share the exact code, but I've tried to share a sample.

Comment: Then post code of A anfd B that reproduces the problem.

Comment: At least order of instructions in you example is incorrect: Firstly you create `A` instance while passing `b` in constructor, next you are creating `b`. 
Please provide working example - it could be on stubs. The best will be one that we could copy and run.

Comment: I rectified that a minute ago, sorry.

Comment: Could you provide implementation of A, B, C? It does not need to be the same as in your example - just ones that enable reproducing the problem. Next important thing: Which mockito version are you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using Mockito in your test. I have recently used it on a project and I did a test project with the following.

First a service (A) with uses another class (B).

```
    public class Service {

    private NonStaticClass nonStatic;

    public NonStaticClass getNonStatic() {
        return nonStatic;
    }

    public void setNonStatic(NonStaticClass nonStatic) {
        this.nonStatic = nonStatic;
    }

    public int useStaticService () {
        return 2*StaticClass.staticMethod();
    }

    public Integer getLastUse () {
        return this.nonStatic.getLastUse();
    }
}
```

Then here is the (B) class:

```
    public class NonStaticClass {

    private Integer lastUse = new Integer(0);

    public Integer getLastUse() {
        return lastUse++;
    }
}
```

In order to test everithing is working i created a test for it.

```
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestNonStaticMock {

    private final Integer staticMethodOutput = 10;

    @Mock
    NonStaticClass mock = new NonStaticClass();

    @InjectMocks
    Service service = new Service();

    @Before
    public void before () {
        setMock();
    }

    private void setMock() {
        when(mock.getLastUse()).thenReturn(staticMethodOutput);
    }

    @Test
    public void mockNonStaticMethod () {
        Integer result = service.getLastUse();
        System.out.println(result.toString());

        Assert.assertEquals(staticMethodOutput, result);
    }
}
```

Hope it can be usefull.

Comment: Thanks, but the difference is: while you've been able to mock NonStaticClass, I can't because it has a protected constructor.

Comment: A protected method means that you can access that method only in the same package or in classes that extend the one which has the protected method. Have you tried to implement the test in the same package??